# C# Generic high performance vectorized math operations

Tags: c#, performance, generics, vectorization

I'm writing a library which simplifies the usage of intrinsics in C#.
It's a generic library which supports all numeric types.
The goal of this library is to perform these operations at the highest performance possible.
I'll gladly head any suggestions / tips which might improve the performance.
All feedback is welcome.

The whole library could be viewed at https://github.com/giladfrid009/SimpleSIMD

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SimpleSimd
{
    // For value delegate pattern, which will allow to inline delegates.
    // The performance benefits of this pattern is quite massive (up to 5x)
    public interface IFunc<T, TResult>
    {
        TResult Invoke(T param);
    }
    
    // Example usage of value delegate pattern. These structs will be passed to the method
    // instead of regular delegates. 
    // We use structs to prevent heap allocations 
    struct Pred : IFunc<int, bool>
    {
        int num;
        
        public Pred(int num)
        {
            this.num = num;
        }
        
        public bool Invoke(int param)
        {
            return param == num;
        }
    }
    
    struct VPred : IFunc<Vector<int>, bool>
    {
        public Vector<int> vec;
        
        public VPred(Vector<int> vec)
        {
            this.vec = vec;
        }
        
        public bool Invoke(Vector<int> param)
        {
            return param == vec;
        }
    }
    
    internal static class SimdOps
    {
        // Helper method to offset a ref, to eliminate bound checks when accessing an index
        internal static ref U Offset<U>(this ref U source, int count) where U : struct
        {
            return ref Unsafe.Add(ref source, count);
        }
    }      
    
    public static partial class SimdOps<T> where T : unmanaged
    {
        // Helper method to get a ref to the first element of a span, without bound checks.
        // Also, by getting a ref instead of a pointer, we no longer need to fix the object
        private static ref U GetRef<U>(ReadOnlySpan<U> span) where U : unmanaged
        {
            return ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(span);
        }
        
        // Helper method to convert ref type
        private static ref Vector<U> AsVector<U>(in U value) where U : unmanaged
        {
            return ref Unsafe.As<U, Vector<U>>(ref Unsafe.AsRef(value));
        }
        
        // The actual method
        public static int IndexOf<F1, F2>(in ReadOnlySpan<T> span, F1 vPredicate, F2 predicate)

            where F1 : struct, IFunc<Vector<T>, bool>
            where F2 : struct, IFunc<T, bool>

        {
            ref var rSpan = ref GetRef(span);

            int i = 0;

            if (Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated)
            {
                ref var vrSpan = ref AsVector(rSpan);

                int length = span.Length / Vector<T>.Count;

                for (; i < length; i++)
                {
                    if (vPredicate.Invoke(vrSpan.Offset(i)))
                    {
                        int j = i * Vector<T>.Count;
                        int l = j + Vector<T>.Count;

                        for (; j < l; j++)
                        {
                            if (predicate.Invoke(rSpan.Offset(j)))
                            {
                                return j;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                i *= Vector<T>.Count;
            }


            for (; i < span.Length; i++)
            {
                if (predicate.Invoke(rSpan.Offset(i)))
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }
    }         
    
    
}
```

Comment: Not worth an actual answer... you should make `Pred` and `VPred` readonly structs. It opens up some additional optimisation opportunities for the compiler (e.g. preventing defensive copies) which _may_ be beneficial.

Comment: This isn't enough for an answer, so I'll post a comment instead: Naming guidelines. .NET favours readability over brevity. Instead of `struct VPred` it should (probably) be `struct VectorPredicate`, instead of `SimdOps` it should be `SimdOperations`. You should also not use abbreviations, so instead of `GetRef` it should be `GetReference`. .NET itself breaks some of these guidelines at some points (e.g `IPAddress`), but it's good to stick to them yourself. [source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions)